# Forward the Signed document to other recipient for signing on same document using DocuSign with C#

Tags: docusignapi

In my application there is Operator and Payor, both will have to sign using embedded url one after one. 
Once Payor's signing process gets completed, I need to forward signed mail to the Operator by adding Operator as a Recipient for completion of process.

Can you please help me out in with this scenario, How do I send the signed document (by Operator) to the Other Recipient for signing the document.

Also, Once the Recipient also sign's it How do I retrieved the Documents signed by both the Parties using DocuSing API.

Comment: Hi,

I'm OK with the Downvote.
But just need to know the reason "Whether the question is irrelevant?" OR "Did I failed to ask the query, justify what I am struggling with?"

This is the Issue where I'm stuck, so need to know what went wrong..

Answer (score 0):

First, you say "embedded url" but then say "forward signed email" so that contradicts. Signing based on an email is "remote signing" whereas signing embedded means inside your app and there's no email. Which one is it?
You only need to define 2 recipients with routing order if you know who they are.
If you want to have the first recipient decide who the second one is - you need a special kind of recipient that is called "Editors" or "Intermediaries"
See https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/concepts/recipients for all recipient types.